# What is the mix of maturities of outstanding US Treasury bonds called?

Tags: finance, financial-markets, usa

What is the technical term for the mix of maturities of outstanding US Treasury bonds? Also, is there an "official" source for this information?

I tried searching to find out, but not knowing what the correct term for the maturity mix is, I got no hits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weighted Average Maturity of Marketable Debt